# why I cannot change my background for a div

Tags: css, html

This is my coding, I want to change my background-image, but it seems not working.
I have tried this coding, it is not working, i don't know what's wrong.

```
<header style="background-image:url('C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/desktop/images/navigationBackground.jpg')"></header>
```

Comment: Are you running your website local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using full path of file instead of URL.
Change url to `http://localhost/images/navigationBackground.jpg`, or better without server name, just relative url `images/navigationBackground.jpg` (and move image to web accessable location instead of desktop)

Comment: oh, it is working if i change the url of a website, is it just can use the website pictures?

Comment: @user3487875 if you change website name, than `images/navigationBackground.jpg` will still be available, unless you change inner files of webpage. And obvious that if you move your web to external server, than `C:/...` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the url of the image, instead of the filesystem path

Comment: oh, what if i want it from localhost?

Comment: most likely (impossible to know without seeing your file structure) then, it would be the following relative URL: "images/navigationBackground.jpg". See https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp for details on relative and absolute URL paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your webpage path. You can put all your resources in a single folder and just specify the url of your image, instead of using filesystem path.